# How to Name a .csv file using the input from a text box as the file name?

Tags: c#, winforms

```
   using (StreamReader sr =   new StreamReader (Convert.ToString(adsClient.ReadAny(hActVel, typeof(double)))))
   using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(NameYourFile.Text + DateTime.Today.ToString("MM_dd_yyyy") + ".csv"))
   {
       if (sr == null)
           return;

       string line;

       while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
       {
           string[] columns = line.Split(',');
           sw.WriteLine(hActVel);
       }
   }
```

and also i want an answer for  how to write Text box  data(i.e double) which is changing every second to ( .c s v) file? in c# windows form..

I am using this app in My project to create Front end for the servo motor .

I already tried this question in

http://area51.stackexchange.com

but i dint get any answer....please help me..

Comment: It is not clear what are you trying to do. Your current code is opening a file to read, reading everyline to it then writing the value of hActVel to an output file. There is no relation between the file you open for read and the one you open for write (expect for number of lines). If you want to add a value to a file, you can add the following code when text in the text box changes (or every second)
StreamWriter writer = File.AppendText("Path of File");
writer.WriteLine("Some Value");

Comment: Thank you for replying me, actually I have two text boxes, in that one text box is to be used to name a .csv file(It is not happening), and in another text box I am reading a data (Variable name-hActVelo), and I need to write this data to the .csv file I have specified in the first text box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume you have 2 TextBoxes ValueTextBox and FileNameTextBox. If the value in the ValueTextBox is changing automatically you can register the TextChaned event and append text to the file as follows:

```
private void ValueTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    StreamWriter writer = File.AppendText(FileNameTextBox.Text);
    writer.WriteLine(ValueTextBox.Text);
    writer.Close();
}
```

Or you can use a Timer control that will fire every second to read the value from the ValueTextBox and append it to the file.

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    StreamWriter writer = File.AppendText(FileNameTextBox.Text);
writer.WriteLine(String.Format("{0},{1},{2}", DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss"), BigMotorTextBox.Text, SmallMotorTextBox.Text)); 
    writer.Close();
}
```

Based on your last comment:

In form load, create the file and write the header to it, as follows:

```
private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("Path_Of_The_File", false);
    writer.WriteLine(String.Format("{0},{1},{2}", "\"Time\"", "\"Big motor Actual Velocity\"", "\"Small Motor Actual Velocity\""));
    writer.close(); 
}
```

In the Timer tick event, write **only** the values as follows:

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    StreamWriter writer = File.AppendText(FileNameTextBox.Text);
    writer.WriteLine(String.Format("{0},{1},{2}", DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss"), BigMotorTextBox.Text, SmallMotorTextBox.Text)); 
    writer.Close();
}
```

Comment: Thank you ...your code is working for me .and i need one more help i need to add headers to .c s v file bellow is my code

Comment: Hi @GopalNavi, adding a header to the .csv file is just writing the a line to the file. Maybe on Form_Load event you can create the file and add the header to it, e.g. writer.WriteLine("Column1, Column2");. After that whenever the Text changes keep adding lines to the file as shown in the answer.
If the code is working please mark my answer as the question answer.

Comment: i want to add bellow code as header and i am writing this code under timer tick event . writer.WriteLine(String.Format("{0},{1},{2}", "\"Time\"", "\"Big motor Actual Velocity\"", "\"Small Motor Actual Velocity\"")); but these headers are writing ever row along with variables simultaneously . and also please tell me how can i append particular variables data under particular column name.......         thank you...

Answer (score 3):

To create a file with the name as textbox:

```
string path = @"D:\"+NameYourFile.Text+".csv";
File.Create(path).Dispose();
```

OR you want to write text to it:

```
    string text = textbox.text;   // your textbox
 // WriteAllText creates a file, writes the specified string to the file, 
    // and then closes the file.
    System.IO.File.WriteAllText(path, text);
```

Writing textbox to CSV file:

```
        //string filePath = @"C:\test.csv";  
        string delimiter = ",";  
        string outputtofile = textbox.text;

        int length = outputfile.length;  
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();  
            for (int index = 0; index < length; index++)  
                sb.AppendLine(string.Join(delimiter, output[index]));  

            File.WriteAllText(path, sb.ToString());
```

if you have text like this in textbox Abcdefg
then it will right to file like:
A,b,c,d,e,f,g

Comment: really its helping but the text box data which i am going to write to file is floating point  and continuously changing with time i.e i am reading it from communication cable to text box . now how can i write text box data to .csv file

Answer (score 1):

finally my code becomes like this..

```
         private void WriteToCSV_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
              {
       string path = NameYourFile.Text + "_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("MM_dd_yyyy") +                        ".csv";
       if (!System.IO.File.Exists(path))
       {
           // Create file if no Exists
           using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(path))
           {
               sw.WriteLine(string.Format("{0},{1},{2}", "\"Time\"", "\"Big Motor Actual Velocity\"", "\"Small Motor Actual Velocity\""));
           }
       }

       this.timer2.Start();
   }

   private void CreateCSVFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {

       this.timer2.Stop();

       MessageBox.Show("File is Created");

   }

   private void timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {


       string dt = DateTime.Now.ToString("hh.mm.ss.ffffff");
       string var1 = (dt);
       string var2 = adsClient.ReadAny(hActVel, typeof(double)).ToString(); ;
       string var3 = adsClient.ReadAny(hSActVel, typeof(double)).ToString(); ;
       StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(NameYourFile.Text + "_" + DateTime.Today.ToString("MM_dd_yyyy") + ".csv");


       {

           if (BigMotorActualVelocity.Checked && SmallMotorActualVelocity.Checked)
           {
               sw.WriteLine(string.Format("{0},{1},{2}",var1, var2, var3));

           }

           else if (BigMotorActualVelocity.Checked)
           {
               sw.WriteLine(string.Format("{0},{1}",var1 , var2));
           }

           else if (SmallMotorActualVelocity.Checked)
           {
               sw.WriteLine(string.Format("{0},{1},{2}",var1," ",var3));
           }
           else
           {
               sw.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}",var1));
           }

           sw.Dispose();

       }
```